# java process does not shutdown even after javac exits on MacOS X

Tags: java, macos, process, javac

I am using MacOS X 10.5 and it appears to me that the java process would not stop even after all the java source files get compiled successfully by the javac. I have to manually "**force quit**" the process from the activity monitor each time after javac executes or any other java related process is executed.

Any idea why is the java process getting stuck and not being terminated ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should send a QUIT signal to the java process and take a look at the thread dump which should be sent to the console.

```
ps auxww | grep java
```

Look for the process-id field of your java process:

```
kill -QUIT pid-from-ps-above
```

This will dump (usually to `System.out`) a list of all of the threads.  Look for the threads that are not marked as daemon threads.  Those threads have to exit on their own for the process to stop.

See here for more information:

> http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/Stacktrace/